# How to select an element by ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the following jQuery code to add a div with class `col_box` inside the `col_left` div:

```
$('#col_left').add('div').addClass('col_box');
```

My DOM tree looks like this:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
    <div class="col_container">
            <div id="col_left">
                <div class="col_box">A</div>
                <div class="col_box">B</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

However the jQuery code isn't working. It adds the class `col_box` to every element on the page.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? If you add an empty div, how is it suposed to show up?

Comment: -1. Please spend time reading the jQuery documentation, going through some tutorials, etc. This is such a basic question that it's clear you haven't done either of those things.

Comment: Read the documentation before you use the method: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.add()` adds a selector to the selection, it doesn't create or add elements.

- `$('#col_left')` means *select element id col_left*
- `.add('div')` means *add all divs of the page the the selection*

  So at this point you've selected #col_left and all the divs.
- `.addClass('col_box')` means *add the class col_box to all elements of the selection*.

Here is how to create a div and add it to #col_left:

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('col_box').appendTo('#col_left');
```

Or:

```
$('<div class="col_box"></div>').appendTo('#col_left');
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#col_left').add('div')` is adding all `<div>` elements to the original selection. Try using `$('#col_left').append('<div class="col_box"></div>')` instead (or `.prepend`).

Answer (score 1):

`$('#col_left').add('div')` means the same as `$('#col_left, div')`. i.e. "The element with the id 'col_left' and all div elements.

If you want to select the divs that are children of col_left, just use a [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

```
$('#col_left > div').addClass('col_box')
```

Comment: I want to add a div element to col_left not select the children divs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

[`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) appends after the matched target

```
$('#col_left').append(
$("<div/>",{class:'col_box'}).html("div added")
);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R65cn/4/